# Rotating solenoid motor vs loop motor

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

My understanding is that this motor works because the solenoid is being constantly repelled by the magnets in the direction of rotation. So it makes sense to me. The question is that does this motor have the same principle as those with "rectangular loop" rotors as shown on  most textbooks?

[image: this guy] <- this guy

From my attempt at explaining the first motor, it seems like they operate based on different principles. However, upon further inspection the motor effect is just a result of magnetic interactions, so really the two motors are the same.

Clarifications would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *twinkl.com* diagram has an error in in which I have corrected in the diagram below by changing the arrows which show the direction of the current.
This error might be the reason for the question?

[image]

Looking down, the current in the loop is flowing counter-clockwise and so behaves like a north pole.  That being the case that face of the loop is repelled by the north pole of the permanent magnet and attracted to the south pole of the permanent magnet resulting in a clockwise rotation.

Comment: You're right, the diagram is incorrect. However this doesn't change my point. But I think you did answer my question, in that the two motors act with the same mechanisms. Just one more question though, how does this explanation of the generation of torque (in that one face is north the other south) compare to the motor effect force explanation provided by the diagram? Are they equivalent? if so, how? thanks

Comment: They are equivalent although perhaps it is more obvious when one deals with forces and the resulting torques?